# Laravel - Has Relationship Through

Tags: php, database, laravel

Let's say I have three tables:

```
1. Server
-------
id
name

2. Player
-------
id
name
ServerId

3. Activity
-------
id
PlayerId
action
time
```

How would I use Laravel's [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to able to get a list of activity from a server's players like so `$system->activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as follows:

```
// this should be inside your Server model.
public function activities()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Player::class,
        Activity::class,
        'PlayerId', // Foreign key on activities table...
        'ServerId', // Foreign key on players table...
        'id', // Local key on servers table...
        'id' // Local key on activities table...
    );
}
```

This will give you all the server activities through the player.

Comment: first argument will be your final model while second argument will be your intermediary model.